# RecyclerView how to setOnClickListener on every item?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

What I want this code to do is: whenever the user clicks on the item (example: like or dislike),
I want something to happen to my firebase (eg. set the value of the like to 1).
I'm trying so hard to set a click listener for every item (like, dislike, happy emote, report).
Even if I set the click listener inside the static class, I can't call my Database Reference.
I also tried to do CommentsActivity.this.mReviewsDatabase..etc but it doesn't work because it doesn't want a static class. And if I remove the static from the class, the app crashes.

```
public class CommentsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mCommentList;
    public DatabaseReference mReviewsDatabase;

    private FirebaseUser mCurrentUser;

    private ImageView happyEmote, thumpUp, thumbDown ,reportReview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_comments);

        String title = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXTRA_SESSION_ID");

        mCurrentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


        mReviewsDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Film_reviews").child(title);

        mCommentList = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.reviews_list);
        mCommentList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mCommentList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllCommClass, CommentsActivity.ReviewsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<AllCommClass, CommentsActivity.ReviewsViewHolder>(
                AllCommClass.class,
                R.layout.comment_single_layout,
                CommentsActivity.ReviewsViewHolder.class,
                mReviewsDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(CommentsActivity.ReviewsViewHolder reviewsViewHolder, AllCommClass allCommClass, int i) {
                reviewsViewHolder.setUsername(allCommClass.getUsername());
                reviewsViewHolder.setReview(allCommClass.getReview());
                reviewsViewHolder.setVoto(allCommClass.getVoto());

                reviewsViewHolder.setReport();
                reviewsViewHolder.setLike();
                reviewsViewHolder.setDislike();
                reviewsViewHolder.setHappyEmote();

                reviewsViewHolder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {                    }
                });
            }
        };
        mCommentList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }





    public static class ReviewsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public ReviewsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;

        }
        public void setReport() {
            ImageView reportReview = mView.findViewById(R.id.reportReview);
            reportReview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("Tag","You've reported the comment number "+getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

        public void setLike() {
            ImageView thumpUp = mView.findViewById(R.id.thumbUp);
            thumpUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("Tag","You've liked the comment number "+getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

        public void setDislike() {
            ImageView thumpDown = mView.findViewById(R.id.thumbDown);
            thumpDown.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("Tag","You've disliked the comment number "+getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

        public void setHappyEmote() {
            ImageView happyEmote = mView.findViewById(R.id.happyEmote);
            happyEmote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.v("Tag","You've added a reaction to the comment number "+getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

        public void setUsername(String username){
            TextView titleView = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_username_comment_section);
            titleView.setText(username);
        }
        public void setReview(String review){
            TextView titleView = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_review);
            titleView.setText(review);
        }

        public void setVoto(int voto){
            TextView titleView = mView.findViewById(R.id.user_single_rating);
            titleView.setText(String.valueOf(voto));
        }
    }}

"
```

Comment: Please include your an recyclerView Adapter class

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 ways as a beginner to set click listener to a recycler view item.

1. The first was is the easy but nonoptimal way to do it. Inside your onBindViewHolder of your adapter class set an onClickListener to your holder.itemview
2. The second way is to use an onClickInterface and then call it from the calling/main activity. Please  let me know if you need any further guidance

Comment: The only problem is that I cannot call the database reference into the static class.
How can I change the code in order to make that work?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

When we are fetching data from firebase

1. The process is to match the Id of the item on firebase you are fetching through your model class to populate your recycleView.
2. If you want your application to remember the number of like or dislike on a certain button you need to set count on the id of the item on which the user will perform the click.
3. You can show that count or keep track of the button click in that manner.

If you need the code for it let me know

Comment: The only problem is that I cannot call the database reference into the static class.
How can I change the code in order to make that work?

Thank you for your time.